# Blowup and Complete Scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

A scheme is complete if the structural morphism to $\mbox{Spec}(K)$ is proper. Let $\pi : \widetilde{\mathbb{P}^{3}} \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{3}$ be the blowup of $\mathbb{P}^{3}$ along of a subvariety $\mbox{Z}$ with $\mbox{codim}(Z) > 1$. Is $\widetilde{\mathbb{P}^{3}}$ a complete scheme? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is complete.

Comment: Ok. Thank you, Sasha.